# Edit local zone content in Orchard CMS 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms-1.10

I use Orchard CMS 1.10.1. I Edited the Content-Summery template. It has three local zone: header, content and footer. Now I need to edit the content local zone template.

How can I access local zone content template to override it on my theme?

Comment: are you talking about the template that is used to render zones? If so you should just be able to add an alternate named Zone.cshtml

Comment: I need to override local zone content for Content_Summery shape. u mean content.cshtml works in this case?

Comment: That should be pretty straightforward, if you enable the shape tracing module in the backend you should be able use those tools to identify the appropriate shape you are trying to create an alternate for.

Comment: Thanks mate. It helped a lot.